# What’s a good way to create an overlay view that would stay on top?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I’d like to create a small overlay view that would float on top of all the others. I need the view to accept touches and I need it to stay in place even during transitions between the underlying views. What I have tried so far:

1. Standalone view inserted into the key `UIWindow`. The obvious downside is that the view is not attached to any view controller, which means handling (at least?) rotation events by hand.
2. `UIViewController` containment, have a “root” view controller that would contain the floating view and all navigation would be done underneath it. This is very much a “first-class-citizen” solution, but presenting a modal view controller overlaps the floating view.
3. Second `UIWindow` with a root view controller containing the floating view. This goes against Apple recommendations and I had some trouble filtering which events should go to which window.

Does anyone have a working solution that doesn’t require too much brittle hacking?

Comment: I implemented your first approach, works fine. Handling the rotation is not that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have followed Jonathan’s suggestion and implemented the overlay as a separate view inserted into the key window. The view has an associated controller object (a subclass of `NSObject`, not `UIViewController`), and this controller takes care of the rotation logic. That way the view implementing the actual overlay object doesn’t need to care about rotation events at all.